# Array's elements become randoms in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have opened a 2d array in main and i am trying to add items to it in an another function. Information correct in the function but outside of the in the main its elements became random things.

```c
void addpassenger(char** seatedbus,char** seatedeco,char** seatedstd,int busct,int ecoct,int stdct){

    busct++;
    seatedbus=realloc(seatedbus,sizeof(seatedbus)*busct);
    addtoarray(seatedbus,"bus",busct-1);
    ecoct++;
    seatedeco=realloc(seatedeco,sizeof(seatedeco)*ecoct);
    addtoarray(seatedeco,"econ",ecoct-1);
}

void addtoarray(char** array,char* item,int index){
    array[index]=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(item));
    strcpy(array[index],item);
}

int main() {
    char** seatedpassengerbus=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    char** seatedpassengereco=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    char** seatedpassengerstd=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    int busct=0;
    int ecoct=0;
    int stdct=0; 
    addpassenger(seatedpassengerbus,seatedpassengereco,seatedpassengerstd,busct,ecoct,stdct);
    return 0;
}
```

this is a basic structure of what i am doing since it is big assignment for my schoolwork i can't share every part of the code but these are generally where problem occurs, any idea why it is happening and how can ı solve it?

Comment: What is `addpassenger`?

Comment: You are allocating `sizeof(char)*1` (which, BTW, is always 1, since `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition) when your elements (in that dimension) are `char *`, so you should be allocating `sizeof(char *)`. Better yet, I suggest following the pattern `arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * count)`, so you don't have to repeat the type.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and format your code correctly and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Blaze sorry i write the functions name wrong i edited it

Comment: There is no 2D array in the code!

Comment: Also, strings in C have a terminating NUL (zero) byte, you need to add one to `strlen(str)` to allocate space for it.

Comment: `seatedbus=realloc(seatedbus,sizeof(seatedbus)*busct);` Args are passed by value in C. That means `seatedbus` allocation there is not seen by the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You forget that `strlen` doesn't count the string null-terminator. Which means

   ```
   array[index]=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(item));
   ```

   will allocate one byte to little, and that

   ```
   strcpy(array[index],item);
   ```

   will therefore write out of bounds leading to *undefined behavior*.
2. You forget that arguments in C are passed *by value*, by copying the value into the functions local argument variable. So when you do e.g.

   ```
   seatedbus=realloc(seatedbus,sizeof(seatedbus)*busct);
   ```

   you only assign to the *local* `seatedbus` variable inside the `addpassenger` function. This assignment will not happen to the `seatedpassengerbus` variable in the `main` function.

One possible way to solve the second problem is to *emulate* pass by reference, by using the address-of operator `&` to pass a pointer to the variable `seatedpassengerbus`. That unfortunately means you will become a [three-star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) as the `addpassenger` function needs to be modified to use triple-pointers (which you need to dereference).

Comment: what can i do the prevent this from happening

Comment: using triple pointer will be a headache but thanks for the advice if there is nothing else i can do to make it work i guess i am becoming three-star programmer sadly.